# PhP postgres inventory issues

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to get an admin site working in which the admin user can enter fields into a form and fill the database with information. this is the main part of the php code:

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
  

  $name = pg_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $price = pg_escape_string($_POST['price']);
 
  // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
  $sql = pg_query("SELECT id FROM beer WHERE name='$name' LIMIT 1");
  $productMatch = pg_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
    echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="inventory_list.php">click here</a>';
    exit();
  }
  // Add this product into the database now
  $sql = pg_query("INSERT INTO beer (name, price) 
        VALUES('$name','$price', now())");
     $pid = pg_insert_id();
  // Place image in the folder 
  $newname = "$pid.jpg";
  move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
  header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

When I try to enter the fields into the website page I keep getting the warnings:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns LINE 2: VALUES('djsd','4', now()) ^ in /home/s14266/public_html/groupA5/storeadmin/inventory_list.php on line 44
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_insert_id() in /home/s14266/public_html/groupA5/storeadmin/inventory_list.php on line 45

I'm not sure what's going on!

Comment: You are listing two columns in your query but trying to insert into three. Hence the "INSERT has more expressions than target columns".

Comment: And the second error, where did you see the `pg_insert_id` function? I know there is a `mysql_insert_id` function but this isn't mysql. Not all the functions have a 1 to 1 correlation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your table's `Column Names` but your query should like this. You got warning because you put value for three columns but you specify only two, in this case `name` & `price`.

```
$sql = pg_query("INSERT INTO beer (name, price,date)  
                                               ^^^^//change as per yours
        VALUES('$name','$price', now())");
```